# React Native: Why doesn't <TextInput/> center with flexbox?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, reactjs

In React Native, I have a `<TextInput/>` but with flexbox style set to center it, yet it still does not and rather just sits to the left but only vertically centered. I tested it out with simple `<Text/>` and it centers correctly.

How can I center `<TextInput/>` with flexbox?

Here is the code:

```
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{fontWeight: 'bold', height: 18, color: 'red'}}
          placeholderStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}
          placeholderTextColor='red'
          placeholder='Center Me'
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT - with additional styles added**

```
  <View style=style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1,}}>
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={this._handleName}
      value={this.props.name}
      placeholderTextColor='white'
      placeholder='Put in name'
      style={{
          backgroundColor: 'black',
          borderWidth: 0,
          borderRadius: 15,
          width: 250,
          height: 70,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontSize: 20,
          textAlign: 'center',
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `textAlign: 'center'` to your TextInput component.

`style={{fontWeight: 'bold', height: 18, color: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}`

The actual element is center aligned, but textAlign controls the alignment of the inner text and placeholder.

[The result of adding the change to your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfIBm.png)

Comment: before I accept the answer and upvote, please take a look at my original post with updated styles, but it still aligns to the left and not the center. What am I missing?

Comment: checking to see if you've my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: If you give the <TextInput /> component a width, that overrides the `alignItems: center` component of the parent <View />.

So you can do this instead `style={{
             backgroundColor: 'black',
             borderWidth: 0,
             borderRadius: 15,
             marginLeft: 50,
             marginRight: 50,
             height: 70,
             fontSize: 20,
             textAlign: 'center'
         }}`

Comment: Having no width, and just a `marginLeft` and a `marginRight` exactly equal to each other makes the component appear centered.